# How to use Preboot mixins in a Rails project with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm looking for a way to use the Less Preboot mixins in my Rails project.

**Gems** `Gemfile`:

```
gem "less-rails"
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

**Layout** `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
```

**Stylesheet** `application.css.less.erb`:

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require_self
 */

.navbar .navbar-inner {
  #gradient > .vertical(#333,#000);
}
```

But the Preboot mixin `#gradient > .vertical` is not found, giving this error:

```
#gradient > .vertical is undefined
  (in */app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.less.erb)
```

The Bootstrap Github page tells me it was built with Preboot:

"Bootstrap was built with Preboot" (Source: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-with-less)

Comment: try to define `.navbar .navbar-inner` inside the `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file

Comment: That seems to work.. Do you have an idea how/what I should include to get it to work in another file..?

Comment: I believe you have to define everything in this file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to define - override the styles provided by Twitter Bootstrap - all the css components in the `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file. You can create your `ids` and `classes` through your application and define the style in this file... Well, this is the way I use `twitter-bootstrap-rails`...

There are other options... this article compare some of them: http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/

Also, there is a very good railscast about it: http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics?view=asciicast

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Preboot mixins in your Rails project with twitter bootstrap you need to add the following to the top of the LESS file you want to use them in:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/variables";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/mixins";
```

After this you are able to use the gradients, and all other Preboot mixins:

```
#content {
  #gradient > .vertical( #eee, #ccc );
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that is adds the content of the variables and mixins file to each of your own less files. This happens because each directive included in the manifest of the asset pipeline has its own scope. It blows up your generated application.css and I haven't found a way yet to resolve this and being able to use the mixins of twitter bootstrap.